# Calculating $\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots +\sqrt{2}}}}}_{100\;\text{times}}$ without a calculator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, nested-radicals

Is there any way to find the summation up to $100$ times without using calculator?

$$\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots +\sqrt{2}}}}}_{100\;\text{times}}$$

I know that if the above summation would be up to $\infty$ then we can find the summation up to infinity very easily.

First we will take the summation to be $x$ and then we will get a quadratic like $x^2-x-2=0$. Now we have to solve the quadratic and get the value of the summation very easily and the value of the summation will be $2$.

But how to find the summation in this case for 100 times 2?

Kindly help me out with this question.

Comment: The linear algebra tag does not apply.  This is also recursive with $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$ so if you can solve that you're done.

Comment: But how to solve. That is only my doubt.

Comment: For n= infinity we can solve easily. But what for n=100?

Comment: Not sure what you are after.  The recursion is easy to run, though the answer is so close to $2$ that your program will likely report $2$.    The wikipedia article on [nested radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) gives some formulas which might be relevant.

Comment: Is there any formula for this question?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $f(x)=2\cos x$. From the half-angle formula for cosine and all terms being positive, render $f(x/2)=\sqrt{2+f(x)}$.

Can you continue from there?

> To the significant figures shown: $1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999985$.

Comment: Yes you are correct@Oscar Lanzi. But what I will do with this relation because according to your relation I can say that f(1/2)=root over (2+f(1)). But is it true? How f(1/2) can come in this question.

Comment: This question deals fully with integers. So, I don't think f(1/2);f(3/2);... will come in this question.

Comment: If $f(x)=\sqrt2$, what should $x$ be in the first quadrant? (It is _not_ rational.) Then what happens with the identity I gave when you keep dividing this $x$ by $2$?

Comment: But how to proceed after this relation? Your relation between f(x) and f(x/2) is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the sequane
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2^2}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt 2$$
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2^3}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2^4}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$$
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2^5}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$$

which are obtained using systemetically the double angle formula for the cosine.

So

$$\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)== \frac 12 \underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+\cdots \sqrt{2}}}}}_n$$ Therefore
$$\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+\cdots \sqrt{2}}}}}_n=2 \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$$

So, using the series expansion of the cosine, to second order
$$2 \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^n}\right)=2 \left( 1-\frac {\pi^2}{2^{ 2 n+1}}+\frac 13 \frac {\pi^4}{2^{4n+3}} \right)$$

$$\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+\cdots \sqrt{2}}}}}_n\sim 2-\frac {\pi^2}{4^n}$$

For $n=100$, you should obtain $119$ exact significant figures.